ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when running Linear Regression model
I am doing a Kaggle competition on predicting house sales using regression models. I have converted the categorical data into a float using OneHotEncoder using a pipeline. However I keep getting the following error when I try and run the Linear Regression model at the end:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I think the error relates to an earlier part of my code where I am using OneHotEncoder to convert the categorical values to numerical and then turn it back into a DataFrame.
#apply preprocessing to the columns
housing_prep = preprocessing.fit_transform(X)
X_transformed = pd.DataFrame(housing_prep, index=X.index)
X_transformed.head()

And it is not converting but I can not be sure that is the case. As it only refers back to the Linear Regression Model. I have put the code for the Pipeline and Regression model below:
    X = housing[['Id', 'MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'Street',
       'Alley', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig',
       'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType',
       'HouseStyle', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd',
       'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType',
       'MasVnrArea', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual',
       'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinSF1',
       'BsmtFinType2', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'Heating',
       'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF',
       'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath',
       'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'KitchenQual',
       'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Functional', 'Fireplaces', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType',
       'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'GarageQual',
       'GarageCond', 'PavedDrive', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF',
       'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'PoolQC',
       'Fence', 'MiscFeature', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'SaleType',
       'SaleCondition']]
y = housing["SalePrice"]

    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_selector, make_column_transformer
#make the pipelines
num_pipeline = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='median'),
                            StandardScaler())

cat_pipeline = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),
                            OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))

#create the transformer
preprocessing = make_column_transformer(
    (num_pipeline,make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
    (cat_pipeline,make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)),)

#apply preprocessing to the columns
housing_prep = preprocessing.fit_transform(X)
X_transformed = pd.DataFrame(housing_prep, index=X.index)
X_transformed.head()

#split the model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_transformed, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#apply Linear Regression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
lin_pred = lin_reg.predict(X_test)

lin_rmse = mean_squared_error(y_test,lin_pred, squared=False)
lin_rmse

Here is a link to the full code https://www.kaggle.com/code/redbullgivesuwind/house-sales
I would appreciate any help
